# Looking at the stacktrace on Android device without logcat

Tags: android, logcat

Does the Android API have a built-in facility to display the stack trace on the device (not via Logcat) without writing too much code when an ANR or exception gets raised?  Something like:

```
LogMode.enableDeviceStackTrace()
```